# Multinomial naive bayes classifier returns different results on same data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes, random-seed

I've been using MultinomialNB classifier from sklearn.naive_bayes library on vectorized text data.

```
make_pipeline(
            TfidfVectorizer(),
            MultinomialNB(
                alpha=0.1,
                fit_prior=True,
                class_prior=self.class_prior
            ),
        )
```

After some data preprocessing (lower text, stemming, stopwords removal,...) and training I'm saving the trained model into model.sav file for later prediction. I tried to train two models with same training data, saved in two different files. How is it possible, that the prediction results and probabilities for same input are different?

**model 1 prediction**

```
{
    "class": 2,
    "probability": 0.554312
}
```

**model 2 prediction**

```
{
    "class": 1,
    "probability": 0.530134
}
```

As I know, the MultinomialNB does not use any random state or seed or something, that could cause this, or does it?

Comment: does it stay consistent if you fix a random seed?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. What random seed do you mean, please? I didn't find any seed parameter in documentation here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html

Comment: I've tried to add random.seed(<int>) before whole classification, and it did not help.